# the apps suddenly freeze after getting the response from server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried to get a response from the server using axios, but then my web application froze instantly when the response was received by the client side
i got the error like this in my console

> Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope
>   ‘http://localhost:3000/’: Load failed with status 404 for script
>   ‘http://localhost:3000/sw.js’.

Comment: I don't work with `vue.js` but sounds like the javascript execution thread is getting blocked while the library fails to get a `ServiceWorker` going.

Comment: Without some code it's hard to tell what is happening.